# np.where multiple condition on multiple columns

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a 2D array and a working code with np.where() condition on one column. I need to enhance this code by adding one more condition by adding an extra filter.

for an array like this:

```
array([[  1,   2,   3],
       [ 11,  22,  33],
       [101, 202, 303],
       [100, 200, 303],
       [111, 222, 333]])
```

my condition is working fine where index 2's column value is 303

```
a = np.delete(a, np.where(a[:, 2] == 303), axis=0)
```

Now I need to add one more condition, where index 1's value equals to 200.
I tried adding np.all for multiple conditions as mentioned below, but it doesn't solve the purpose.

```
a = np.delete(a, np.where(np.all((a[:, 2] == 303) & (a[:,1] == 200)) ), axis=0)
```

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Using logical_and explicitly, then recasting to 'not' is another possibility.

```
w = np.logical_and(a[:, 2] == 303, a[:, 1] == 200)

a[~w]

array([[  1,   2,   3],
       [ 11,  22,  33],
       [101, 202, 303],
       [111, 222, 333]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Just drop the np.all()

```
def twoCond():
    a = np.array([[  1,   2,   3],[ 11,  22,  33],[101, 202, 303],[100, 200, 303],[111, 222, 333]])
    a = np.delete(a, np.where((a[:, 2] == 303) & (a[:,1] == 200)), axis=0)
    return a
```

Results:

```
>>> twoCond()
array([[  1,   2,   3],
       [ 11,  22,  33],
       [101, 202, 303],
       [111, 222, 333]])
```

Comment: Thanks. It resolved my issue. I tried this too, but I missed adding extra brackets around each condition.